# Box Enterprise API: Where do my files "live"?

Tags: python, box-api, box

I have a Box Enterprise account with Box Developers features turned on.  I was able to create a Box developers app, create the necessary authentication, and use it to very simple Python script using the SDK to create a folder, upload a file, etc.

However, when I log in to my Box account, the files aren't there, nor can I see other files in my Box account when calling the API from within Python.  Where is this space, and can I access it from my regular Box login?

From within the API, I can do a call to see where I am, but I don't recognize this space:

root folder owner: `AutomationUser_[string]@boxdevedition.com`

root folder name: `All Files`

`client.user(user_id='me').get().name:   [Name of my app, in my Box dev console]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a new application is created in the Box Developer Console, a [Service Account](https://developer.box.com/docs/service-account) is [created](https://developer.box.com/docs/getting-started-box-platform#section-overview).

> Service Accounts are not visible to standard Box Users as they do not represent an individual user, but rather an application. To view the content of a Service Account, an Administrator can use the Global Content Manager in the Box Admin Console to view the Service Account and all of its associated content.

To view the content of a Service Account,

1. From https://app.box.com/, in the left sidebar, go to "Admin Console".
   ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F5Mp.png))
2. Go to Content Manager (3rd tab - folder icon -
   https://app.box.com/master/content). You'll find the service account listed there from which you can see it's contents. ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6mBI.png))

Comment: You can also give yourself access to the folder you are uploading, using the same service account.